# Grub: configuration to boot on specific partition without menu

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed Grub on a UEFI bootable key, this works fine.

Now **I want to use this key to boot on a single partition, containing an installed Ubuntu**.

I would like Grub to choose it immediately, without showing the menu.

I am kind of a newbie to this, and didn't find ressources for this specific case. Is this doable ?

Comment: I understand this might seem a weird way to do it, but it is part of a small DIY project.

Comment: First, you want to set grub to select your partition by default.  Second you want to set the grub timeout to 0 so you skip past the grub menu

Comment: Thanks. Is there any ressource i could use to know how to set grub to select the specific partition ? I can not find the syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was just looking through the grub man pages, and I don't see much documenting `/etc/default/grub`, just the tools that process it.

Comment: It's in the GRUB Manual: [6.1 Simple configuration handling](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration)

Comment: If the install is on another UEFI bootable drive, you can just edit /EFI/Ubuntu/grub.cfg. Or you can create your own grub.cfg that has a standard boot stanza to boot your install. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen And lots of discussion (start at end of mega thread like this for latest info). https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205

Comment: Ok I was able to make it work with the ressources you gave me. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` in `/etc/default/grub`.  This means grub will always use the entry you selected last.

Run this to apply your change:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Next reboot, and select your partition from the grub menu when it appears.  That will be your new default selection.  Next you wanted to eliminate the grub menu:

In `/etc/default/grub`, set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`.  This will effectively bypass the grub menu, and always boot into your default selection.  Apply this change with this command again:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```